# Importing questions from SO

Tags: discussion

SO has quite a few questions tagged [[latex]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex). Is it considered acceptable to go through those and reask the best ones here, or is that sort of question importing frowned upon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are also a few on mathoverflow that could also be imported.

I would propose the following guidelines:

1. Only ask the question *if* when reading it you think, "Hmm, I'd like to know the answer to that one too.".
2. Only ask the question if it hasn't been satisfactorily answered.
3. Re-ask the question rather than just cut-and-pasting it.
4. Link back to the original question.

Obviously, for a really great question these could be broken.  The point of 1 and 3 is that if, as an answerer, I want to clarify some details before posting my answer then I don't want to go back to the original site and ask them there.  I want to leave a comment and get some meaningful response from you, the asker.  So 1 and 3 are there to ensure that I don't get the response "Dunno, I just copied this from SO."

Answer (score 3):

All of the trillogy sites' content is licensed under the CC Wiki, Attribution, which means that this usage is encouraged.

Please, however, remember to link to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

See also this [meta thread on stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56511/tex-latex-questions-on-this-site-and-the-proposed-site-at-area51-for-the-same) (and I apologize for being impatient in the first comment there:))

Answer (score 1):

I think yes. In fact, I’ll go ahead and ask one from Super User which hasn’t really been answered satisfactorily there.

Answer (score 1):

I think so, provided they were not answered there - either of the Trilogy sites.

Answer (score 1):

I think questions tagged [tex] or [latex] from other SE sites should actually be moved over here. If the goal of an SE site is to be *the place* on the Internet with answers to questions about X, then the collection of SE sites should be managed as such.